# How to find multiple files with specific pattern using or in find command

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bash, find

Is it possible within the find command to use or to specify multiple patterns to look for using regex or any other means? For example, I am looking for all files that aren't `.bashrc` or `.profile` in a certain directory. The following doesn't function, but gets the point across of what I am trying accomplish:

```
find . ! -name "(.bashrc|.profile)"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
! \( -name '.bashrc' -o -name '.profile' \)
```

Ex.

```
$ find /etc/skel ! \( -name '.bashrc' -o -name '.profile' \)
/etc/skel
/etc/skel/.mkshrc
/etc/skel/examples.desktop
/etc/skel/.kshrc
/etc/skel/.bash_logout
```

The quotes aren't actually necessary in this case but you should get in the habit of using them in the case that the search pattern contains glob characters.

Comment: Won't the `!` interfere with that awful (and mostly useless) bash history thingy?

Comment: @PerlDuck a `!` on its own is OK I think (though you will see people backslash escape it just in case) - AFAIK it's only a problem when `!` is followed by another non-whitespace character